# React Router v4 Component not loaded on button submit

Tags: react-router, react-redux, redux-form, react-router-redux, react-router-v4

I have a login form and when I click login, the URL is updated but the component is not. (e.g. localhost:8080/somewhere but still on login page)

The versions of my packages are as follows:

- react - 15.4.2
- react-router & react-router-dom - 4.1.1
- redux-form - 6.6.1

This is the Login component

```
class Login extends React.Component {
handleFormSubmit = ( values ) => {
  this.props.signInUser(values);
  history.push('/somewhere');
};
<div>
   <div>
      <h2>Log In</h2>
      <form onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit( this.handleFormSubmit ) }>
        <Field name="email" type="text" label="Email"/>
        <Field name="password" type="password" label="Password"/>
        <button action="submit">Sign In</button>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
...
}
export default connect( mapStateToProps, Actions, )( reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
  validate,})( Login ));
```

I am using **history.push** because I have a shared history object.

My routes are as follows:

```
   <Provider store={ store }>
      <Router history={history}>
        < App >
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
            <Route path="/login" component={ Login } />
            <Route path="/somewhere" component={ Somewhere } />
          </Switch>
        </ App >
      </Router>
    </Provider>
```

I tried using `<Redirect>` but can't get it to work. Also tried using `withRouter` but discovered this is only applicable for components not declared in the routes.

How do I redirect to the **Somewhere** component when submitting the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the best way to do this, but it works for me :

```
<form onSubmit={ this.props.handleSubmit( this.handleFormSubmit ) }>
   <Field name="email" type="text" label="Email"/>
   <Field name="password" type="password" label="Password"/>
   <button action="submit">Sign In</button>
   {this.props.user.loggedIn && <Redirect to={'/Somewhere'} />}
</form>
```

Given the fact that `this.props.handleSubmit( this.handleFormSubmit )` dispatches an action who toggles to true the `loggedIn` prop of `user`.

You have to map `user` to props, for your component to re-render when `user.loggedIn` is changed. The `<Redirect>` will then be activated.

Comment: Figured out that I did not map props in the mapStateToProps. Thank you so much!